# create a variable in a struct and access the variable in the same struct

Tags: swift, xcode, struct

I'm trying to add a custom font to a swift project and have a question for Swift's struct. Since I'm gonna make custom fonts with different sizes and I need to use string ("My custom font") multiple times, I want to make a variable for the strings but get the error.

```
struct Fonts {

    let myFont = "My custom font"
    let myFontBold = "My custom font bold"

    static let customFontNormal = UIFont(name: self.myFont, size: 16.0)
    static let customFontBold = UIFont(name: self.myFontBold, size: 16.0)
}
```

and I get this error message

> Cannot use instance member 'myFont' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available.

I want to call the font like Fonts.customFontNormal or something similar, but is there a way to make a string variable and enable to access the value from a variable in the same struct?

Comment: Why would you use `static` for some of this, but not all? 
Unrelated, the type is `enum Font`, not `struct Fonts`. But why bother making a type instead of just extending `UIFont`?

Comment: Thank you Jessy.
Sorry I'm still a beginner of Swift stuff and I just followed Sean Allen's video to make a custom UI.
https://youtu.be/C4f7R2gUO8E?t=279

Comment: In the video, he only makes a fonts title for the struct but that was my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Jessy, I extend UIFont and add a new struct for the sting.

```
struct Fonts {

    static let myFont = "myFont"
    static let myFontBold = "myFontBold"
}


extension UIFont {

    static func myFontNormal() -> UIFont {
        return UIFont(name: Fonts.myFont, size: 16)!
    }

    static func myFontBoldNormal() -> UIFont {
        return UIFont(name: Fonts.myFontBold, size: 16)!
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!